# i have problem to get new inserted columnID using sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have an identity column defined as int in sql .
I use SCPOE_IDENTITY () to get the new inserted column id.

this is sample of my code:

```
     Dim sql As String = "insert into infoHotel (nameHotel, knownAs1, knownAs2, knownAs3, knownAs4, streetAddress) values (N" & _
                                       FormatSqlParam(hotel) & ",N" & _
                                       FormatSqlParam(KnownAs(0)) & ",N" & _
                                       FormatSqlParam(KnownAs(1)) & ",N" & _
                                       FormatSqlParam(KnownAs(2)) & ",N" & _
                                       FormatSqlParam(KnownAs(3)) & ",N" & _
                                       FormatSqlParam(StreetAddress) & _
                                       "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)")"

    Dim objCommand1 As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

    Dim infoID As Integer = objCommand1.ExecuteScalar()
```

my problem here is, i cant get the infoID's value..is my code wrong?..some help plzz..
im using vb.net n sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a bracket and the end of your SQL statement.

It should read

```
FormatSqlParam(StreetAddress) & ")" & _
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to commit your changes to the database before you can query it...

Comment: -1 You don't need to commit to read any changes you made using the same connection.